# Python code compilation issue

Tags: python

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, mark):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.mark = mark

std1 = student("name1", 14, 45)
std2 = student("name2", 13, 90)
std3 = student("name3", 14, 70)
std4 = student("name4", 14, 80)
std5 = student("name5", 13, 75)

listofStds = ["std1", "std2", "std3", "std4", "std5"]
for x in sorted(listofStds,key=lambda x: x.mark):
   print x
```

Please help. I'm a python beginner and I am trying out this simple sorting program using classes but I keep getting the following errors

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mark'

Comment: Please make sure when you post an error message, you post the full stack trace (the part starting with "Traceback") with it.

Comment: listofStds = [std1, std2, std3, std4, std5] remove all "", since you want the objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`listofStds` is a list of strings, not a list of `student` instances. You are trying to sort it by attribute `mark` which doesn't exist for strings.

You probably wanted to have a list of `students`, so you need this:

```
listofStds = [std1, std2, std3, std4, std5]
```

Comment: Please let me know how to fix it. I'm a total beginner.

Comment: @user2655793, Zdeslav Vojkovic's answer contains the fix.

Comment: @user2655793 change the line listofStds just as Zdeslav Vojkovic's answer states.

Comment: I'm getting the following output with the fix:

<__main__.student instance at 0x022180D0>
<__main__.student instance at 0x02218120>
<__main__.student instance at 0x02218170>
<__main__.student instance at 0x02218148>
<__main__.student instance at 0x022180F8>

Comment: @user2655793: `"std1"` is a string with the text `std1` in it. `std1` is a reference. You want references.

Comment: @user2655793: Try to print the name of the student instances instead of the instance itself: `print x.name`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I understand the issue now. Thanks for spoon feeding me the fix. You guys are the greatest.

Comment: @user2655793 If you want to control the string representation of the object, look up `__str__`, `__unicode__` and `__repr__` methods. Also, the Python tutorial is an excellent resource in general: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/.